# Javascript - Ignore Quotes when sorting array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, quotes

I haven't found a good solution to this yet. I have an array of strings used in a glossary pop up. The strings are keys and are used to retrieve definitions out of an object. I need the array to be sorted alphabetically but some of the strings contain quotes and end up appearing first when sorted.

```
    keys = ['Back Pay', '"Hot Cargo" Agreements', 'Clayton Act', 
    'Fiduciaries', 'Estoppel', ...]
```

When sorted I want the list to ignore the quotes and be the following:

```
    ['Back Pay', 'Clayton Act', 'Estoppel',
    'Fiduciaries', '"Hot Cargo" Agreements', ...]
```

but I get the following:

```
    ['"Hot Cargo" Agreements', 'Back Pay', 'Clayton Act', 'Estoppel',
    'Fiduciaries',  ...]
```

Is there a way to ignore the quotes during sorting without stripping them off? They are part of the term and need to be there when displaying them in the glossary pop up.

Comment: you can write own [sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and sort as you wish

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a custom sort function using

```
myArray.sort(mysortfunction);
```

Then in your function strip the quotes

```
function mysortfunction(a,b) {
  a = a.replace(/"/g,'');
  b = b.replace(/"/g,'');

  return (a < b ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfovc3rm/1/).

Comment: if not mistaken, _compareFunction_ should return _0_,_greater than 0_ or _less than 0_ instead bool value

Comment: Even easier: `return a > b;`

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom sort function that ignores quotes:

```js
var keys = ['Back Pay', '"Hot Cargo" Agreements', 'Clayton Act', 'Fiduciaries', 'Estoppel'];

function removeQuotes(str) {
  return str.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
}

var sorted = keys.sort(function(a, b) {
  return removeQuotes(a) > removeQuotes(b);
});

console.log(sorted);
```